# how to get textSize value of a textview from XML and set it in code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, text-size

I want to set the textSize value of the snippet below to a textSize of an XML file, how to achieve this?

```
holder.tvValue.setTextSize();
```

in the xml it is like this:

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_title"
   android:textSize="32sp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: You want to change the size of your text dynamically or what ?

Comment: exactly, I need a responsive text. On a 10.5" device the text is one size, on a 8.5" device the text is another size.

If I used an xml in layout-Xlarge and layout it would switch sizes by itself

Comment: so try to use this line of code holder.tvValue.setTextSize(20f), your post is right, but you forget to add the size as parameter, setTextSize need a parameter of type Float

Comment: I want to get this parameter from a TextSize from an xml file

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Java here.
This method `TextView.setTextSize(float size);` requires you to enter a value as the parameter.
Try entering `holder.tvValue.setTextSize(32f);`.
Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Find the [[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29)][1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29) for more details.

Example:

```
holder.tvValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 65);
```

OR
Cleaner and more reusable approach is

define text size in dimens.xml file inside res/values/ directory:

```
</resources>
   <dimen name="text_medium">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and then apply it to the TextView:

```
holder.tvValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium));
```